# Handle latency issues when two REST end points read the same data

Tags: java, mongodb, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have two rest api's. I use Spring Boot and MongoDB.

Firstly the client invoke the api1 which insert a record to a mongo collection. 
Then after few seconds, the api2 try to read the insert record and do some process.

But there are situation some times when the api2, try to read the record, it was not insert to the collection due to latency by api1.

In that case, the api2, is not able to do the process.

One option I can think of it, when the api2 read the record, and if it's still not insert in to the mongo, sleep the thead for few seconds and wake it (can do few time till the record exists)

What other options I have?

Update:
The two api's are independent. The flow is like when upon finish upload a video it calls api1 and insert a media with a refid and that flow finish. Then application receive a callback from a external video processing system to api2, after video transcode completes (usually after 30s or so) with the refid, which api2 then do some updates to the inserted media. There is a edge case, for very small size video the external video system act fast and gives the callback where at that time my application still inserting the media to the mongo

Comment: Why not use an event system ? put your data in a broker, then process by a listener that will do process and store data to DB

Comment: @wargre Well the two api's are independent. The flow is like when upon finish upload a video it calls api1 and insert a media with a refid and that flow finish. Then application receive a callback from a external video processing system to api2, after video transcode completes (usually after 30s or so) with the refid,  which  api2 then do some updates to the inserted media. There is a edge case, for very small size video the external video system act fast and gives the callback where at that time my application still inserting the media to the mongo.

Comment: @Harshana, sounds a bit too complex... I would still go either with api1 calling api2 once it is done or api1 publishing the event once it is done and however wants to (api2 in your case) registers for this event and takes action.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that your api1 once its done invokes api2 and passes it the id that it inserted. This way api2 would never have to run prematurely. The other way is to use a queue where api1 will place a message and api2 consumes the message and processes it (credit to @warge user who mentioned it in his comment)

Comment: I have add a comment to @warge. Pls have a look

Answer (score 0):

From your usecase you have not so much choice.

the clean way to do it is to create the document at upload time, so that that api1 and api2 will be update on that, and there will be no "not found" exception.